# Google Cloudprint printer implementation

Tags: c#, printing, printers, google-cloud-print

Can someone give a reference or working example of a printer implementation using Google-CloudPrint?

I am looking for code + instructions on how to register the printer.

I want to create some print management software, where i would like my software to be able to register as a printer in google cloudprint.

I can find some examples of printing to cloudprinters, this is not what i am looking for.

Also a some examples are using deprecated authentication, i would like a working example.

Answer (score 0):

- The [printer/connector documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/proxyinterfaces) is pretty good
- Some example code (Go) can be found in the official [Google Cloud Print CUPS Connector](https://github.com/google/cups-connector)
- More example code (Python) can be found in the [Google Cloudprint Proxy](https://github.com/armooo/cloudprint)